# Python - Question about initialising lists with [None] versus with just []

Tags: python, list, nonetype

I'm currently looping over some lists of strings to populate a new list. Originally I had:

```py
z_locations = ['50', '100', '150', '250', '500']
path = [None]
for counter, value in enumerate(z_locations):
   path.append('Desktop/Data/z_' + value)
```

My list `path` would come out as a list of length 6, with the first element in my new list `path` would be simply `NoneType`. I can fix this by changing to:

```py
z_locations = ['50', '100', '150', '250', '500']
path = []
for counter, value in enumerate(z_locations):
   path.append('Desktop/Data/z_' + value)
```

Which removes the `NoneType` being the first element and only copies as I had originally intended. However, I am unsure why this was happening in the first place. I have not encountered this `NoneType` before in creating new lists. Could someone please enlighten me as to why this happens?

Thanks.

Comment: `[None]` is a list with one element. `None` is an object, and its type is `NoneType`. If you want an empty list, you want `[]`. What made you think you should use `[None]`?

Comment: "However, I am unsure why this was happening in the first place." *because you put `None` in your list*

Comment: Can I just say @Juanpa my question is asking 'I'm not sure why this doesn't work' and your answer is essentially mocking saying 'it doesn't work because it doesn't work', which is not entirely helpful. People will ask dumb questions - sometimes that is how we learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is happening because `append` adds an element to the end of the list.  Your list all ready has `None` in it so any elements you add are going to be put after it, like this `[None, ...]`.  Therefore when you get the first element, it gives you `None`.

Comment: Ah sorry, deleted my comment. It's a separate issue that I've run into before where it will say `list assignment out of range`. I will just go back and have a look though

Comment: Oh, that makes sense.  Its because when you do that your list is empty ```path = []```.  Therefore there is no index 0.  This may be difficult to grasp if you are coming from another programming language, like java for example, where arrays are initialized with null values.  In Python though, the list is empty until you add an element.  If you put blank values in your ```path``` list, ```path = [None for _ in z_locations]``` then your ```path[counter] = ...``` will work.  The ```out of range``` means you are trying to use an index that doesn't exist.

Comment: Ohhhhhhhh! Thank you! Yeah I am coming from other languages. This makes a lot of sense. Thank you Salty